# Selecting a null option

Tags: jquery, select

I have a strange problem with this piece of code:

```
<select name="nazioni" id="nazioni">
  <option selected="selected" value="val">Seleziona</option>
  <option value="0">text 1</option>
  <option value="1">test 2</option>
</select>
```

The correct behavior with this HTML should be that the selected option is "Seleziona".
On some browsers, when I render this HTML, the first option is blank and if I select the value `jQuery("#nazioni").val()`, I get a null value.

Where is the problem? With the select option in this state, I cannot set any values via jQuery or via any other plugin.

`jQuery("#nazioni option:first").attr("selected", "selected");` does not work.
I tried using the textotela plugin (http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/), but if I remove the first option using `jQuery("#nazioni).removeOption(0)`, it removes the "Seleziona" value.

Any idea?

Kind regards,

Massimo

Comment: What browsers does it not work on for you?  I've run your code on every browser and it works fine for me.

Comment: Is it possible that you have used "nazioni" as the "id" for more than one element? In other words, is that `<select>` the only thing on your page with "id" equal to "nazioni"?

Comment: also make sure you have valid html in the rest of the page

Comment: Ok thank's all.
It was the jQuery form plugin.
The clearForm() function set the select value to -1.
Damn...
Kind regards
Massimo

Comment: Hi Massimo, for the sake of cleaning things up I suggest you add this as an answer and accept it to close this question off.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting Massimo's comment as an answer to this question:

> The problem was that the clearForm() function set the select value to -1.